# How Calculate the electric field into capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

Hello i have a problem with this exercise with capacitor,
I have to calculate the electric field between the capacitor plates (neglecting the edge effects ),
but I do not know how to do

**Text**:
A plate capacitor has circular plates of r1 = 25 cm radius , far apart h = 2.5 cm ; in
a space of N toroidal winding is inserted between the plates , coaxial with the axis of symmetry and perpendicular to this ,
N= 10^3
coils with a rectangular section with sides a = 2 cm and b = 1 cm, the average radius is r2 = 20 cm . The capacitor is
connected through a resistance R0 = 0 Ω ( IGNORE THE RESISTANCE ) to a generator of e.m.f. alternating
100 V rms and frequency  = 13.56 MHz . Consider the e.m.f. to the heads of the generator as a wave
sinusoidal .

Comment: This looks like part of a problem to do with the "observation" of the displacement current demonstration?  The electric field inside the capacitor is the potential gradient inside the capacitor.